# Call to a member function get_row() on a non-object, Unable to use global $wbdp inside a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a custom plugin for my wordpress site.

I made a php file call "checkrank" that obtains data from a custom table named "cranking"

```
$uid = $GET['id']; 

function checkExists($id){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'cranking';
    $exists = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id = %d" ) );

    $error = $wpdb->print_error();

    if(count($exists) > 0){
       echo 'Exists!';
    } else {
       echo 'Does not exist!';
    }

 return $error;
}

 checkExists($uid);
```

The code is just to check whether the cranking table has the user with id provided.

The problem is, whenever i run this php file, i get this error :
**PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_row() on a non-object**

Where am I at fault here? i think $wbdp is not initiated.

Comment: who is using globals these days????

Comment: I think you gave your own answer there. You can check what $wpdb contains by using `var_dump()`. Maybe that'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$wpdb::prepare()` is missing arguments, you need to add an argument `$id` if you wrote `%d` in the query.

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

```
$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id = %d", $id )
```